# in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file: No such file or directory

Tags: r

I am trying to upload a file of csvs and other documents into R studio. My code looks like the following.

```
setwd("~/Dropbox/R")
getwd()
[1] "/Users/me/Dropbox/R"
myData <-read.csv("~/Dropbox/Exercise_Files")
```

The message returned is:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file '/Users/me/Dropbox/R/Exercise_Files': No such file or 
directory
```

I can't understand why R is telling me no such directory when getwd() shows the directory I am using. Nor do I understand why I am being told that there are no such files--I put them into the directory! They are right there! Please help; I have tried everything.

Comment: Can you show `list.files("/Users/me/Dropbox/R")`

Comment: Is Exercise_Files the name of a CSV file? It's unusual that there is no .csv or .txt in the file name.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the .csv extension:

`myData <-read.csv("~/Dropbox/Exercise_Files.csv")`

Comment: The file was a whole folder. Specifying one single csv in the file like the example below gets the same error message. List files showed that the folder Exercise_Files is in there!

Comment: myData <-read.csv("/Users/me/Dropbox/R/Exercise_Files/02-02/exploratory-r.csv")

Comment: @A.Fuller Reading in a file, or every file within a folder are two different problems. For reading a single file, I'd try specifying the full path, on Windows `"C://Users/User/Dropbox/R/Exercise_Files/02-02/exploratory-r.csv"`

Comment: Thank you Mako212

Answer (score 0):

`list.files()` worked for me. I discovered that all my text files were being seen in `R` as `filename.txt.txt` but were seen as `filename.txt` in the Windows file manager. I changed the files to filename (without '.txt') in Windows and now they read into `R` correctly.